# How to override StepLabel default label?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tsx

### I am trying to override the StepLabel to remove the values("1", "2", and "3") inside of each StepLabel.

[Image of the current status bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwff6.png)

As seen in the image, the Stepper has numbers inside each node/cirlce.

I've created a CustomStepLabel based on Material-UI documentation but it did not work as expected or something is missing.

Link to StepLabel docu: https://material-ui.com/api/step-label/

I tried to set labelContainer : {fontSize: 0, and display: 'none'} in the CustomStepLabel but it did not make any changes to the text and I can still see the numbers in the circles.

```
    import React from "react";
    import {
      makeStyles,
      Theme,
      createStyles,
      withStyles
    } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Stepper from "@material-ui/core/Stepper";
    import Step from "@material-ui/core/Step";
    import StepLabel from "@material-ui/core/StepLabel";
    import StepConnector from "@material-ui/core/StepConnector";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import COLORS from "theme/colors";
    
    const QontoConnector = withStyles({
      alternativeLabel: {
        top: 10,
        left: "calc(-50% + 16px)",
        right: "calc(50% + 16px)"
      },
      active: {
        "& $line": {
          borderColor: COLORS.black,
        }
      },
      completed: {
        "& $line": {
          borderColor: COLORS.black,
        }
      },
      line: {
        borderColor: "#eaeaf0",
        borderTopWidth: 3,
        borderRadius: 1
      }
    })(StepConnector);
    
    const CustomStepLabel = withStyles({
      labelContainer: {
        fontSize: 0,
        display: 'none'
      },
      MuiStepIcon: {
        text: {
          fontSize: 0,
          display: 'none'
        }
      }
    })(StepLabel);
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
      createStyles({
        root: {
          width: "100%",
        },
        button: {
          marginRight: theme.spacing(1)
        },
        instructions: {
          marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
          marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
        },
        label: {
          fontSize: 0
        }
      })
    );
    
    function getSteps() {
      return ["Order Placed", "In Progress", "Shipped"];
    }
    
    function getStepContent(step: number) {
      switch (step) {
        case 0:
          return "Order Placed";
        case 1:
          return "In Progress";
        case 2:
          return "Shipped";
        default:
          return "Unknown step";
      }
    }
    
    const ProgressBar2 = () => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(1);
      const steps = getSteps();
    
      const handleNext = () => {
        setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
      };
    
      const handleBack = () => {
        setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
      };
    
      const handleReset = () => {
        setActiveStep(0);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<QontoConnector />}>
            {steps.map((label) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <CustomStepLabel>{label}</CustomStepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
          <div>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <div>
                <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                  All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
                </Typography>
                <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
                  Reset
                </Button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
                  {getStepContent(activeStep)}
                </Typography>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    disabled={activeStep === 0}
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default ProgressBar2
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to customize the StepLabel following the next steps:

1. Created a component "CustomStepIcon" to replace the current default node.
2. Added styles to the component "useCustomStepIconStyles".
3. Passed in the "CustomStepIcon" component in StepLabel props.

[Click here to see an image of custom StepLabel without the inner text as desired.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZqJe.png)

```
const useCustomStepIconStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#eaeaf0',
    display: 'flex',
    height: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  active: {
    color: COLORS.black,
  },
  circle: {
    width: 21,
    height: 21,
    borderRadius: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'currentColor',
  },
  completed: {
    color: COLORS.black,
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
  },
})
```

```
const CustomStepIcon = (props: StepIconProps) => {
  const classes = useCustomStepIconStyles();
  const { active, completed } = props;

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.active]: active,
      })}
    >
      {completed ? <CheckCircleIcon className={classes.completed} /> : <div className={classes.circle} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
      <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<QontoConnector />}>
        {steps.map((label) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel
              StepIconComponent={CustomStepIcon}
            >
              {label}
            </StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the StepLabel values (1,2,3...) by overriding the root class of **StepIconProps**.
I did something like this:

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<QontoConnector />}>
   {steps.map((label) => (
      <Step key={label}>
         <StepLabel
            StepIconProps={{
              classes: {
                root: classes.stepIconRoot,
              },
         }}>
           {label}
         </StepLabel>
      </Step>
   ))}
</Stepper>
```

Then export your component like this:

```
const styles = () => ({
  stepIconRoot: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});
    
export default withStyles(styles)(ProgressBar2);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I implemented your suggestion and it removes the whole node (the numbers and the circular container). The goal is to remove the text inside each node which in this case are the numbers 1,2 and 3 and keep the circle. Current ( 1 )--( 2 )--( 3 )  Desired (  )---(  )---(  )   Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with `display: none`

```
  <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepLabel {...labelProps}></StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
```

and style

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    stepper: {
      "& .MuiStepIcon-text": {
        display: "none",
      },
    },
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
```

Answer (score 0):

add sx={{ ".MuiStepIcon-text": { display: "none" }, }} to your StepLabel props and it works.
Example:

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={activeStep} connector={<QontoConnector />}>
  {steps.map((label) => (
    <Step key={label}>
      <StepLabel
          sx={{
            ".MuiStepIcon-text": {
              display: "none",
            },
          }}
        >
          {label}
      </StepLabel>
    </Step>
  ))}
</Stepper>
```